# Why is this matrix initialization giving me unexpected results?

Tags: python

When I initialize a 2-dimensional matrix in the following way, the behavior is very strange to me.

```
In [1]: matrix = [[None] * 2] * 3                                               

In [2]: matrix                                                                  
Out[2]: [[None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]

In [3]: matrix[0][0] = 5                                                        

In [4]: matrix                                                                  
Out[4]: [[5, None], [5, None], [5, None]]
```

I now know I should initialize it in the following way to avoid this strange behavior:

```
matrix = [[None for x in range(2)] for x in range(3)]
```

Can someone explain why in the former case I am getting values duplicated across multiple arrays and is there benefit to this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the values are all the same object, same `id`, so you need to do:

```
matrix = [[None] * 2 for i in range(3)]
```

One `range` can be enough, the `id`s would be different now.

**The reason why it is not working:**

`matrix` variable is containing three identical items, totally the same, not only values are the same, same `id`, when you use `range`, they gonna be processed one by one, not altogether, and so the `id`s would be different,  but values still same, so not all are the same, the stuff mentioned is causing really your problem, `*` isn't always the best, `range` is.